# What does cursive writing of a method name mean in C++ / Qt-Creator

Tags: c++, methods, fonts, qt-creator

I`ve got a quick question :

I`m programming in C++ / Qt-Creator.

In the *.h and the *.cpp-Files I have the name of the methods written in different fonts - Sometimes they are in *cursive letters*, sometimes they are not cursive.

For example what would be the difference between

- virtual void *clearTab*();
- void addStringItems();

My guess is that this is this to distinguish between class-specific methods and inheritable/inheritad methods. Is that true?

Thank you

itelly

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/347236/why-some-function-definitions-appears-in-italic-font-in-qt-creator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to

[Why some function definitions appears in italic font in qt creator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347236/why-some-function-definitions-appears-in-italic-font-in-qt-creator)

QtCreator makes member functions italic in the following cases:

- Virtual member functions (e.g. "virtual void foo();" ), or
- Overridden member functions (derived from a base class)

On the other hand, according to the following forum thread

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42168-qtcreator-v2-2

only virtual member functions are shown italic in QtCreator.

I suggest you to make a small experiment with a base class having both virtual and non-virtual member functions and a derived class overriding both the virtual and non-virtual member functions. Then you can observe which of the member functions in both the base class and the derived class are shown italic.